# How to create a subsubparagraph appearing in the TOC ? (memoir class)

Tags: sectioning, memoir, titlesec

I'am trying to create a subsubparagraph counter.

```
\titleclass{\subsubparagraph}{straight}[\subparagraph]
\newcounter{subsubparagraph}

\titleformat{\subsubparagraph}[display]{\normalfont\normalsize}{}{0pt}{\thesubsubparagraph{#1}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubparagraph}{\roman{subsubparagraph}. }
\titlespacing*{\subsubparagraph} {3.5cm}{*0}{*0}
```

However, the title of this new subsubparagraph is not displayed in my toc.
Example :     `\subparagraph{test}`

Here, there is just the number of the subparagraph displayed in the TOC, but no the "test" title.

How coul I fix this please ?

Thank you

Comment: Could you provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that we can play with? It should be easy since you know which packages you're using to get to your setup, rather than us having to set up a mock document from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Besides defining the sectional unit, you also need to define how the entry will be typeset in the ToC; this can be achieved using `\newlistentry` and `\cftsetindents` (this is the memoir's way of doing it). A complete example (adjust the settings according to your needs):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}

\titleclass{\subsubparagraph}{straight}[\subparagraph]
\newcounter{subsubparagraph}

\titleformat{\subsubparagraph}[display]
  {\normalfont\normalsize}
  {\thesubsubparagraph.}
  {.5em}
  {}
\renewcommand\thesubsubparagraph{\roman{subsubparagraph}}
\titlespacing*{\subsubparagraph} {3.5cm}{*0}{*0}

\newlistentry[subparagraph]{subsubparagraph}{toc}{5}
\cftsetindents{subsubparagraph}{18.0em}{2em}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{Test chapter}
\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection}
\paragraph{Test paragraph}
\subparagraph{Test subparagraph}
\subsubparagraph{Test subsubparagraph}

\end{document}
```

An image of the resulting ToC, showing the new sectional unit entry:

[image]

An image of the document showing the heading of the new sectional unit (as defined in the question):

[image]

By the way, instead of using `titlesec`, you can define the new sectional unit using `memoir`'s native mechanisms (with `\@startsection`) in a similar fashion as the way in which the class defines the lower sectional units.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add something like \setcounter{minitocdepth}{3} (and change the "3" as desired) in your preamble.

Comment: Yeah, thanks but I have already a \setcounter{tocdepth}{11}.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question.